# Laravel dynamic HTML tag name, based on if href is passed

Tags: php, laravel

I have a laravel component

```
<x-link :href="{{ $href }}">
    some text
</x-link>
```

If I don't pass `$href` prop I want to print `span` tag instead, without duplicating code, but on tag directly.

Something like this **that exists in Vue.js** would be nice:

```
<component :is="href ? 'a' : 'span'">
    some text
</component>
```

Comment: Nothing OOB i'm aware of but you can build your own custom Blade [components](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#components).

Answer (score 0):

You could make a new component containing your span and conditionally render it...

```
@if($href)
<x-link :href="{{ $href }}"> some text </x-link>
@else
<x-new-component>
some text
</x-new-component>
@endif
```

Comment: I don't want to duplicate